# Transform from dictionary to array in swift without a for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce

I have some data returned from the server that look like this:

```
let returnedFromServer = ["title" : ["abc",  "def",  "ghi"],

                      "time"  : ["1234", "5678", "0123"],

                      "content":["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvb"]]
```

I want to transform it into something like this:

```
let afterTransformation =

[["title" : "abc",
  "time"  : "1234",
 "content": "qwerty"],

["title" : "def",
 "time"  : "5678",
"content": "asdfg"],

["title" : "ghi",
 "time"  : "0123",
"content": "zxcvb"]]
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
var outputArray = [[String : AnyObject]]()

for i in 0..<(returnedFromServer["time"] as [String]).count {

        var singleDict = [String: AnyObject]()

        for attribute in returnedFromServer {

            singleDict[attribute] = returnedFromServer[attribute]?[i]
        }
        outputArray.append(singleDict)
}
```

This works fine but I think it is not a very elegant solution. Given that Swift has some neat features such as **reduce**, **filter** and **map**, I wonder if I can do the same job without explicitly using a loop.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ideas and the dictionary extension

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(_ pairs: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (k, v) in pairs {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }

    func map<OutKey: Hashable, OutValue>(transform: Element -> (OutKey, OutValue)) -> [OutKey: OutValue] {
        return Dictionary<OutKey, OutValue>(Swift.map(self, transform))
    }
}
```

from

- [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift),

you could achieve this with

```
let count = returnedFromServer["time"]!.count
let outputArray = (0 ..< count).map {
    idx -> [String: AnyObject] in
    return returnedFromServer.map {
        (key, value) in
        return (key, value[idx])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Martin R’s answer is a good one and you should use that and accept his answer :-), but as an alternative to think about:

In an ideal world the Swift standard library would have:

- the ability to initialize a Dictionary from an array of 2-tuples
- a Zip3 in addition to a Zip2 (i.e. take 3 sequences and join them into a sequence of 3-tuples
- an implementation of zipWith (i.e. similar to Zip3 but instead of just combining them into pairs, run a function on the given tuples to combine them together).

*If* you had all that, you could write the following:

```
let pairs = map(returnedFromServer) { (key,value) in map(value) { (key, $0) } }
assert(pairs.count == 3)
let inverted = zipWith(pairs[0],pairs[1],pairs[2]) { [$0] + [$1] + [$2] }
let arrayOfDicts = inverted.map { Dictionary($0) }
```

This would have the benefit of being robust to ragged input – it would only generate those elements up to the shortest list in the input (unlike a solution that takes a count from one specific list of the input).  The downside it its hard-coded to a size of 3 but that could be fixed with a more general version of zipWith that took a sequence of sequences (though if you really wanted your keys to be strings and values to be `AnyObject`s not strings you’d have to get fancier.

Those functions aren’t all that hard to write yourself – though clearly way too much effort to write for this one-off case they are useful in multiple situations.  If you’re interested I’ve put a full implementation in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/3675952127ee775551b0).

Answer (score 1):

I'd create 2 helpers:

ZipArray (similar to `Zip2`, but works with arbitrary length):

```
struct ZipArray<S:SequenceType>:SequenceType {
    let _sequences:[S]

    init<SS:SequenceType where SS.Generator.Element == S>(_ base:SS) {
        _sequences =  Array(base)
    }

    func generate() -> ZipArrayGenerator<S.Generator> {
        return ZipArrayGenerator(map(_sequences, { $0.generate()}))
    }
}

struct ZipArrayGenerator<G:GeneratorType>:GeneratorType {
    var generators:[G]
    init(_ base:[G]) {
        generators = base
    }
    mutating func next() -> [G.Element]? {
        var row:[G.Element] = []
        row.reserveCapacity(generators.count)
        for i in 0 ..< generators.count {
            if let e = generators[i].next() {
                row.append(e)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return row
    }
}
```

Basically, `ZipArray` flip the **axis** of "`Array` of `Array`", like:

```
[
    ["abc",  "def",  "ghi"],
    ["1234", "5678", "0123"],
    ["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvb"]
]
```

to:

```
[
    ["abc", "1234", "qwerty"],
    ["def", "5678", "asdgf"],
    ["ghi", "0123", "zxcvb"]
]
```

Dictionary extension:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_ pairs:S) {
        self.init()
        var g = pairs.generate()
        while let (k:Key, v:Value) = g.next() {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
let returnedFromServer = [
    "title" : ["abc",  "def",  "ghi"],
    "time"  : ["1234", "5678", "0123"],
    "content":["qwerty", "asdfg", "zxcvb"]
]

let outputArray = map(ZipArray(returnedFromServer.values)) {
    Dictionary(Zip2(returnedFromServer.keys, $0))
}
```