# Error: Immutable value passed on reduce function

Tags: swift, dictionary, reduce

I'm trying to do the following code that transforms an array of tuples into a dictionary but I'm receiving a compile error saying:

> Immutable value of type '[String : String]' only has mutating members named 'updateValue'

```
var array = [("key0", "value0"), ("key1", "value1")]
var initial = [String: String]()
var final = array.reduce(initial) { (dictionary, tuple) in
    dictionary.updateValue(tuple.0, forKey: tuple.1)
    return dictionary
}
```

Why is that if **initial** was declared as **var**? Does it have to do with **@noescape** on **reduce's** signature?

```
func reduce<U>(initial: U, combine: @noescape (U, T) -> U) -> U
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply make the `dictionary` parameter mutable by preceding it with `var`:

```
var final = array.reduce(initial) { (var dictionary, tuple) in
                                     ^^^
```

Note however that using `reduce` a new dictionary is created at each iteration, making the algorithm very inefficient. You might want to consider using a *traditional* `foreach` loop

Comment: Thanks a lot! The caveat is that I can't use $0 if I want to change the mutability on those scenarios right?

Comment: I guess so... I am not aware of any method to make it a var (that doesn't necessarily mean it's not possible)

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira: Part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24219069/1187415) is a Dictionary init method which takes an array of key/value tuples (and that uses a simple loop as well).

Comment: I doubt performance is an issue unless you're going to `reduce` it many times/second, in which case a `[(String, String)]` probably isn't a good choice anyway

Comment: Downvote as in Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3) this produces an error stating `'var' parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3`.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4 has a new variant:

```
var array = [("key0", "value0"), ("key1", "value1")]
var initial = [String: String]()
var final = array.reduce(into: initial) { dictionary, tuple in
    dictionary[tuple.0] = tuple.1
}
```

Which could be expressed:

```
var array = [("key0", "value0"), ("key1", "value1")]
let final: [String: String] = array.reduce(into: [:]){ $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
```

Answer (score 4):

On Swift 3:

```
var final = array.reduce(initial) { (dictionary, tuple) -> [String: String] in
    var mutableDictionary = dictionary
    //.... make changes with mutableDictionary
    return mutableDictionary
}
```