# How to convert dictionary to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to convert my dictionary to an array, by showing each `[String : Int]` of the dictionary as a string in the array.

For example:

```
var myDict: [String : Int] = ["attack" : 1, "defend" : 5, "block" : 12]
```

I'm aware of `myDict.keys.array` and `myDict.values.array`, but I want them to show up in an array together. Here's what I mean:

```
var myDictConvertedToArray = ["attack 1", "defend 5", "block 12"]
```

Comment: Note that `myDict.values.array` is now `Array(myDict.values)`

Comment: Is this still valid for Swift 5?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the dictionary key/value pairs to construct your array:

```
var myDict: [String : Int] = ["attack" : 1, "defend" : 5, "block" : 12]

var arr = [String]()

for (key, value) in myDict {
    arr.append("\(key) \(value)")
}
```

**Note:** Dictionaries are *unordered*, so the order of your array might not be what you expect.

---

In **Swift 2** and later, this also can be done with `map`:

```
let arr = myDict.map { "\($0) \($1)" }
```

This can also be written as:

```
let arr = myDict.map { "\($0.key) \($0.value)" }
```

which is clearer if not as short.

Comment: I have that it doesn't support destructuring pari into (key, value) ($0, $1) so I need to use $0.key instead

Comment: @MichałZiobro, I just retested both answers with Swift 4 in Xcode 9.2 and they both work as stated.  What is different about your situation?

Answer (score 20):

The general case for creating an array out of **ONLY VALUES** of a dictionary in Swift 3 is (I assume it also works in older versions of swift):

```
let arrayFromDic = Array(dic.values.map{ $0 })
```

Example:

```
let dic = ["1":"a", "2":"b","3":"c"]

let ps = Array(dic.values.map{ $0 })

print("\(ps)")

for p in ps {
    print("\(p)")
}
```

Comment: You're not gonna tell us the result of the print...?

Answer (score 7):

If you like concise code and prefer a functional approach, you can use the `map` method executed on the keys collection:

```
let array = Array(myDict.keys.map { "\($0) \(myDict[$0]!)" })
```

or, as suggested by @vacawama:

```
let array = myDict.keys.array.map { "\($0) \(myDict[$0]!)" }
```

which is functionally equivalent

Comment: Nice, @Antonio!  It could also be written as `let array = myDict.keys.array.map { "\($0) \(myDict[$0]!)" }`. The performance is the same, and 1 whole character shorter. :-)

Answer (score 7):

With Swift 5

```
var myDict:[String : Int] = ["attack" : 1, "defend" : 5, "block" : 12]

let arrayValues = myDict.values.map({$0})
let arrayKeys = myDict.keys.map({$0})
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to go through and construct a new array yourself from the keys and the values.

Have a look at ['s swift array documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> You can add a new item to the end of an array by calling the array’s
>   append(_:) method:

Try this:

```
var myDict:[String : Int] = ["attack" : 1, "defend" : 5, "block" : 12]

var dictArray: [String] = []

for (k, v) in myDict {
    dictArray.append("\(k) \(v)")
}
```

Have a look at [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift) if you're using Swift 2.0: