# How can I expand a Dict(string, array) in Swift 5

Tags: swift, dictionary

Can I expand the dictionary to an array of pairs in Swift 5 using `map/reduce` or will I have to do a `for each` ?

```
let dict = ["A": ["1","2","3","4"],
            "B": ["5","6","7","8"]]

???

//result = [["A", "1"],["A", "2"],....["B", "5"],....]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert dictionary to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845421/how-to-convert-dictionary-to-array)

Comment: @MQLN doesnt really seems like a duplicate its not the same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = dict.map { (letter: String, digits: [String]) in
    return digits.map { digit in
        return [letter, digit]
    }
}.reduce([]) {
    $0 + $1
}
```

Comment: `reduce([]) { $0 + $1 }` can just be replaced with `reduce([], +)`.  At the minimum, you should use `reduce(into: []) { $0 += $1) }`, or else you get quadratic time complexity, or even better, just use `.flatMap { $0 }`

Answer (score 0):

This one is shortest solution.

```
let result = dict.map { dic in
        dic.value.map { [dic.key : $0] }
    }.reduce([], +)
```

Comment: You should use reduce(into: []) { $0 += $1) }, or else you get quadratic time complexity, or even better, just use .flatMap { $0 }

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't need `reduce`:

```
let dict = ["A": ["1","2","3","4"],
            "B": ["5","6","7","8"]]
let result = dict.map { kv in kv.value.map { [kv.key, $0] } }.flatMap { $0 }
```