# "Ambiguous reference to member map" from concrete type

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code. It uses `CBUUID` which is from Core Bluetooth. Let's just assume the cast of `v` is valid.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

func convert(v: AnyObject) -> [String: String] {
    return (v as! [CBUUID: NSData]).map { (uuid, data) in
        (uuid.UUIDString, NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "") 
    }
}
```

The idea is to get the string representation of the dictionary by calling `CBUUID.UUIDString` for `CBUUID` and by calling the appropriate `NSString` constructor for `NSData`.

I've cast the dictionary to a specific type. Why do I get **"ambiguous reference to member 'map'"** here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that the `map()`
method applied to a dictionary does not return a new dictionary but an array, in your case `[(String, String)]`,
See for example [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift) for a discussion of that topic.

Another problem is that `NSString` is not converted to `String`
implicitly, i.e. `NSString(data: data, ...)` should be replaced by
`String(data: data, ...)`.

Using the extension method

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(_ pairs: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (k, v) in pairs {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }
}
```

from the referenced thread you can return a new dictionary with

```
func convert(v: AnyObject) -> [String: String] {
    let dict = v as! [CBUUID: NSData]
    return Dictionary(dict.map { (uuid, data) in
        (uuid.UUIDString, String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "") 
    })
}
```

Alternatively, change the return type to `[(String, String)]`:

```
func convert(v: AnyObject) -> [(String, String)] {
    return (v as! [CBUUID: NSData]).map { (uuid, data) in
        (uuid.UUIDString, String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "") 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather not use a dictionary extension, and I can use `(String, String)` instead. So I just tried to change the function return type, but it still returns the same error. Any guidance?