# "Ambiguous reference to member map" when attempting to append/replace array element

Tags: swift

Several SO posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849414/ambiguous-reference-to-member-map-from-concrete-type) deal with the same error message, but none of those solutions work. It appears like this could be a case of a misleading error message.

The code below generates an "Ambiguous reference to member map" error for the map call.

Anyone know why?

```
func saveUser(user: User) {
    var userDicts = masterDict["users"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    let newDict = user.getDict()

    // Replace matching element with <newDict>
    let replaced = false
    masterDict["users"] = userDicts.map {
        if ($0["id"] as String! == user.getId()) {
            replaced = true
            return newDict
        } else {
            return $0 as [String:AnyObject]
        }
    }

    // If no match found, means must add new user
    if (!replaced) {
        userDicts.append(newDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like swift is having a hard time inferring type for map.  try `userDicts.map {val -> [String:AnyObject] in`   and swap out `$0` for `val`

Comment: Also,  what version of Xcode are you using,  I can't seem to replicate your exact error,  and the first error I see is "change replaced to a var", so maybe you need to update Xcode.  I am currently on 7.2

Comment: It's not the main problem but `replaced` should be a `var` not a `let`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon sorry, you're right. this was a sanitized version and forgot to replace the `let` for `replaced` but everything else is the same. Using Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately, swift is not perfect and can not infer types at all times,  this is why you are getting the ambiguous reference.  Try `userDicts.map {val -> [String:AnyObject] in` and swap out `$0` for `val`  This will explicitly tell the map that the values coming in are `[String:AnyObject]`, and should be able to return said type

Comment: Do you also happen to know the answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376729/modifying-dictionary-property-inside-of-array-of-dictionaries-error-cannot-ass/34378199#34378199. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never isolated the cause of the error so switched to using a `for` loop, creating a new array inside the loop, and calling `masterDict["users"] = newArray` after the loop. Not the cleanest, but it fixes the error.

Comment: did you try my method of explicitly telling the type ?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the comment. Will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes that appears to work. Could you post as an answer so you can receive credit?