# Save Array of dictionaries with Enum type, NSCoding

Tags: arrays, swift, nscoding

I have been trying to figure out how to save an arrays of dictionaries using Enum types with NSCoding.

I have an enum with Medal types

```
enum Medal: String {
   case Unearned = "NoMedal"
   case Gold = "GoldMedal"
   case Silver = "SilverMedal"
}
```

I have an array of dictionaries with the medal types in my GameData.swift class.

```
var medals: [[String: Medal]] = [
    ["1": .Unearned, "2": .Unearned, "3": .Unearned]
    ...
]
```

Than I have this code in the decoder method

```
convenience required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()

    medals = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(Key.medals) as? [[String: Medal]] ?? medals
}
```

and this is the encoder method which I believe is causing me the issues

```
// MARK: - Encode
func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {

    encoder.encodeObject(medals as? AnyObject, forKey: Key.medals)
}
```

The problem is on a restart it is not saving/loading the medal array, it keeps resetting to default.

I have also tried  this

```
 encoder.encodeObject(medals as? [[String: Medal]], forKey: Key.medals)
```

and it causes a compiler error.

I also cannot use the regular syntax

```
 encoder.encodeObject(medals, forKey: Key.medals)
```

Like I would for a array of dictionaries using normal values (e.g [String: Int]) as the compiler will also throw an error

Comment: `enum`s are not objects so they cannot be casted as `AnyObject`. Try converting `[[String:Medal]]` to `[[String:String]]` and store that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`medals` is not an `AnyObject`, so when you encode it `as? AnyObject` you get `nil`.

Just because the enum has raw string values doesn't mean you can automatically bridge it to `[String:String]`. You have to do that yourself. For example (using [Airspeed Velocity's version of `mapValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461082/97337)):

```
convenience required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()

    if let medalStrings = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(Key.medals) as? [[String: String]] {
        medals = medalStrings.map { $0.mapValues { Medal(rawValue: $0) ?? .Unearned } }
    }

}

func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
    let medalStrings = medals.map { $0.mapValues { $0.rawValue } }
    encoder.encodeObject(medalStrings, forKey: Key.medals)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was just about to post my own, because I realised that the enum is not anyObject. I ended up going for an array of [[String: String]] and just save the enum as Medal.Gold.rawValue in the dictionary. Thanks again for your help