# Convert Any dictionary array to String in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

> Convert [String:Any] dictionary array to [String:String] in Swift

I have an array of dictionary `<String,Any>` type. Now I want to convert to string because I want to show data in `textField` and text field not understand `Any` data type.

My data like this:

```
var myarr = [[String:Any]]()

[
    [
        "Area" : "",
        "Good" : "-",
        "Level" : 2,
        "Link" : "<null>",
        "Photo" : "-",
        "Repair" : "-",
        "Section" : "Others"
    ],

    [
        "Area" : "",
        "Good" : "N",
        "Level" : 2,
        "Link" : "http://google.com",
        "Photo" : 1,
        "Repair" : "Y",
        "Section" : "Grounds"
    ]

]
```

and I want new Array Dictionary:

```
var myarr = [[String:String]]()
```

Comment: You want to convert `[[String:Any]]` to `[[String:String]]` ?

Comment: yes i wan't to convert String String as?String is not work

Comment: What do you want ["test4": true] to convert to?

Comment: @MikeTaverne check my updated question

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44112062/3411787) helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution that actually gives the correct results:

```
let myarr = [
    [
        "Area" : "",
        "Good" : "-",
        "Level" : 2,
        "Link" : "<null>",
        "Photo" : "-",
        "Repair" : "-",
        "Section" : "Others"
    ],

    [
        "Area" : "",
        "Good" : "N",
        "Level" : 2,
        "Link" : "http://someurl",
        "Photo" : 1,
        "Repair" : "Y",
        "Section" : "Grounds"
    ]
]


var newarr = [[String:String]]()
for dict in myarr {
    var newdict = [String:String]()
    for (key, value) in dict {
        newdict[key] = "\(value)"
    }
    newarr.append(newdict)
}
print(newarr)
```

Output:

> [["Level": "2", "Area": "", "Good": "-", "Link": "<null>", "Repair": "-", "Photo": "-", "Section": "Others"], ["Level": "2", "Area": "", "Good": "N", "Link": "http://someurl", "Repair": "Y", "Photo": "1", "Section": "Grounds"]]

Answer (score 7):

Map is your friend, maybe something like

```
let stringDictionaries: [[String: String]] = myarr.map { dictionary in
    var dict: [String: String] = [:]
    dictionary.forEach { (key, value) in dict[key] = "\(value)" }
    return dict
}
```

Comment: thank you it's work properly and not get any error in type converting

Comment: This answer is wrong. It adds an extra layer of arrays to the results.

Comment: please give another solution @rmaddy i am waiting for your solution

Comment: @HarshilKotecha I updated the example using flatMap to flatten the structure to match your desired output. :)

Comment: The update is wrong too. `flatmap` doesn't change anything here. Please verify your answer before posting. A simple test in the playground should be done.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm actually testing this in Playgrounds and the output gives me `[["test1": "123"], ["test2": "345"], ["test3": "657"], ["test4": "true"]]` just like OP is looking for. What do you see in Playgrounds?

Comment: Your test isn't valid. Test with a dictionary that has more than one key/value pair just like the data in the question.

Comment: Print the original array and your result array. Note how the result has a bunch of extra dictionaries.

Comment: @HarshilKotecha Not at all. It has nothing to do with memory. The result is creating a dictionary for each key/value pair found in the original dictionaries.

Comment: @JohnDough check your out put and than my code [["Section": "Grounds"]] it is true ?

Comment: let dict = stringDictionaries[0]

print(dict["Section"]) check this it's not work in your output result

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for staying alert - updated the example to not split into sub-dictionaries. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, that works. You can't use `map` on a dictionary to get a new dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new dictionary using following code:

```
var newArray:[[String: String]] = []
for data in myarr {
    var dict: [String: String] = [:]
    for (key, value) in data {
        let strData = String(describing: value)
        dict[key] = strData
    }
    newArray.append(dict)
}
```

Comment: This code produces the wrong result. It only works if each dictionary has one key/value pair.

Comment: I've edited my code. So now you can check the output.