# Difference between [(key: String, value: String)] and [String:String] dictionary

Tags: swift

I am using this flatmap function to return a dictionary but it is returning  `[(key: String, value: String)]` instead. What is the difference between  `[(key: String, value: String)]`  and a dictionary? Here is the code I am using. What would be the best way to do this. `totalResponseArray` is a custom class of type `Array<Duplet<Product, imageArray>>`.

```
let sizeDict  = totalResponseArray.flatMap { (obj) -> [String:String] in
        var storedItem = [String:String]()
        storedItem["\(obj.one.productID)"] = "\(obj.one.size)"
        return storedItem
    }
```

The other way I can think to do this is using a loop but I feel like there is a cleaner way to do it.

I am trying to apply a flatmap function to an array not a dictionary. The result of the flatmap function should be a dictionary of `[String:String]`.

Here is the result I am trying to get. Is there a better or cleaner way of doing it? I figured out that the above code doesn't make sense to get this same result as the code below.

```
var storedItem = [String:String]()

    for eachItem in totalResponseArray{
        storedItem["\(eachItem.one.productID)"] = "\(eachItem.one.color)"
    }
```

EDIT:
It turns out that the loop is the best way and only way to do it. I am not trying to map the function.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. I am trying to apply a Flatmap function to an array not a dictionary. The result of the flatmap function should be a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. – However, [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift) should be helpful, as it explains the difference between a Dictionary and an array/sequence of key/value pairs. I strongly assume that similar methods can be applied here.

Comment: Maybe give us some sample input plus your expected result to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: I am trying to get a dictionary of [String:String] from an array of custom class. Basically I am looking to loop through the array of custom class and update a dictionary with values for each item in that array. So for each productId, I want to assign a color essentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[(key: String, value: String)]` is not a `Dictionary` but an `Array` of tuples of type `(key: String, value: String)`.