# How to skip nil key-value pair in Dictionary mapping

Tags: swift

I am using custom code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219069/362840) to map a `Dictionary` to a `Dictionary`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(_ pairs: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (k, v) in pairs {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }

    func mapPairs<OutKey: Hashable, OutValue>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> (OutKey, OutValue)) rethrows -> [OutKey: OutValue] {
        return Dictionary<OutKey, OutValue>(try map(transform))
    }

    func filterPairs(_ includeElement: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Key: Value] {
        return Dictionary(try filter(includeElement))
    }
}
```

My `Dictionary` looks like this:

```
[String: (TokenView, MediaModel?)]
```

and needs to be mapped to `[String : MediaModel]`.

Currently this code:

```
let myDict = strongSelf.tokenViews.mapPairs {($0.key, $0.value.1)}
```

maps to `[String : MediaModel?]`.

What needs to happen is that if the `MediaModel` is nil whilst it's being mapped, that key-value pair should not be added to the end Dictionary. How can I modify the code to accommodate for this?

Comment: Why so complicated?  Just iterate the key/values with a `for in` loop, and don't add the value to the output dictionary if the value in the tuple is nil

Comment: @Paulw11, I don't even think you need to check for nil because assigning `nil` as the value will not add the value to the dictionary.  `for (key, value) in dict { newDict[key] = value.1 }` should do it.

Comment: @vacawama good point

Comment: If you would just read comments... 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467101/5774854

Comment: And the other way is to use flatmap, because Flatmap is operator made for removing nil values from Sequences...

Comment: @vacawama yep, used your way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` on the dictionary to get the key/values and construct a new dictionary from the values you get back from the closure:

```
func mapPairs<OutKey: Hashable, OutValue>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> (OutKey, OutValue)) rethrows -> [OutKey: OutValue] {
    return try self.reduce(into: [:]) { result, element in
        let new = try transform(element)
        result[new.0] = new.1
    }
}
```