# Map dictionary with values-arrays to another dictionary with values-arrays in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, mapping, reduce

I have a dictionary of type `[String: [SomeObject]?]` and I want to map it to another dictionary of the same type but in some cases remove elements from the inner array.

How to solve this issue? If it is possible to do with swift features only like `map`, `filter`, `reduce` and etc. without iterating and recreating a new dictionary manually?

Comment: In Swift 4, `Dictionary` has a  [`mapValues(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894692-mapvalues) method. – Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR And? That question is about objects/values which have constant count. My question is about arrays which have varying count of inner elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's say we have the following [String: [Int]]:

```
var dict = ["k1":[-1, -2, 1, 2]]
```

and we want to remap the dictionary removing all the negative elements in the array:

```
dict = dict.mapValues { v in v.filter { $0 > 0} }
print(dict) // ["k1":[1,2]]
```