# Swift 3 : Convert Dictionary of String type to Int

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I' have dictionary

```
var dict: [String: [String]] = ["key1": ["1", "111"], "key2": ["22", "222"]]
```

How i can convert it to  `[String: [Int]]` using map function

```
["key1": [1, 111], "key2": [22, 222]]
```

**NOT** by using `for` OR `forEach` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 4**

You can use `mapValues` (introduced in Swift 4) with an array `map` as follows

```
let newDict = dict.mapValues { value in 
    value.map { Int($0)!}
}
```

Note that your program will crash if the values inside your array can not be converted to `Int`s.

**Swift 3**

In Swift 3, however, there is no `mapValues`. Fortunately, with this extension (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219069):

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(_ pairs: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for (k, v) in pairs {
            self[k] = v
        }
    }
}
```

you can write

```
let newDict = Dictionary(dict.map { (key, value) in 
    (key, value.map{Int($0)!}) 
})
```

which will also achieve the desired result.

Comment: I think that will only work for `var dict = [String: String]`, will it work on `var dict = [String: [String]]` as the question is suggesting.

Comment: @Asis `mapValues` is for the dictionary and `map` is for the array.